# How do you cancel an async operation in C++/CX from C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, c++-cx, cancellationtokensource

I'm trying to cancel an operation that is written in C++/CX from C#.  Despite the fact I wrote both pieces of code I can't get the operation to cancel properly when awaiting it from the C# side.  Here's an example:

From C#:

```
var tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
tcs.Cancel();
var class1 = new MyClass();
try
{
    var asyncOp = await class1.DoSomeTaskAsync().AsTask(tcs.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
{
    //I want to get here
    Handle(oce);
}
```

From C++:

```
IAsyncOperation<bool>^ MyClass::DoSomeTaskAsync(){
        return concurrency::create_async([](concurrency::cancellation_token ct) {
            task<bool> my_task([]() {
                doSomething1();
                if (concurrency::is_task_cancellation_requested())
                {
                    concurrency::cancel_current_task();
                }
                doSomething2();
                return false;
            }, ct);
            return my_task;
        });
    }
```

The problem seems to be that passing in the token into the AsTask extension method does nothing when calling a task across the ABI.  When debugging the C++ side both the ct and the is_task_cancellation_requested() function indicate that a cancellation has not been requested.

Comment: Call `txw.Cancel` after starting the async operation. Make sure your operation last enough to be canceled and ask multiple times if the task has been canceled.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a requirement to cancel a task _after_ it has been started.  What about the condition where you navigate to a page, the page starts a number of tasks that in turn start a number of tasks, and then you quickly navigate away from the page.  There could be some tasks that have yet to be started which you'd want to immediately cancel, right?

Comment: So, you can add a Boolean value to indicate you have decided to go somewhere else, so you do not start any other async operation. My **guess** is that only the tokens generated before the call to `Cancel` will be canceled. So, if you start a chained async operation after calling `Cancel`, it will be canceled as long as the token was generated before calling `Cancel`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In your C++ Windows Runtime Component do something that takes a long time, for example, `concurrency::wait(2000)` will sleep the thread for two seconds (do not do this in a real app).

```
#include <ppltasks.h>

using namespace Windows::Foundation;

IAsyncOperation<bool>^ MyClass::DoSomeTaskAsync()
{
    return concurrency::create_async([=](concurrency::cancellation_token token)
    {
        // Do something.
        concurrency::wait(2000);

        if (concurrency::is_task_cancellation_requested())
        {
            concurrency::cancel_current_task();
        }

        // Do something else.
        concurrency::wait(2000);

        return true;
    });
}
```

Then, in your C# Windows Store App create two buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="DoButton" Click="DoButton_Click">Do</Button>
<Button x:Name="CancelButton" Click="CancelButton_Click">Cancel</Button>
```

Call your component's asynchronous method in the *Do* button.

```
private System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void DoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
    var class1 = new MyClass();
    try
    {
        var asyncOp = await class1.DoSomeTaskAsync().AsTask(cts.Token);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(asyncOp);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {
        // I want to get here.
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(oce);
    }
}
```

And cancel the operation in the *Cancel* button.

```
private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel();
    cts = null;
}
```

Run the app, click `Do` button and within two seconds click `Cancel` button. You should get a `System.Threading.OperationCanceledException`.